# C++ expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++

when trying to calculate volume the value placed before the * will always throw up the error "C++ expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" (in this example pi)

`

```
double eval_volume(double a, double b)
{
    double length = a;
    double diameter = b;
    double pi = 3.142;
    double volume = (pi * (diameter / 2) ^ 2) * length;
    
    
    return volume;
}
```

`

Comment: `^ 2` does not do what you think it does. It's a bitwise XOR

Comment: For power of two, just multiply with itself? Otherwise use [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Comment: *Well, it's "Deja Vu all over again."* The very first computer program that I ever wrote "had a bug in it" because I also did not understand what **the language** meant by what was, to it, "perfectly acceptable syntax." (That was ... *koff koff* ... "quite a while ago, now." But *computers* don't change much ...)

Comment: Since C++20 you can use [`std::numbers::pi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants) for an approximation of pi that's a bit more precise than `3.142`...

Comment: "Beats the heck out of me" why they didn't just use `**` ... like everybody else did.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Why would anyone do that? That's not a valid C++ operator.